# Is it possible to release an app update whithout informing the user?

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise-architecture

I have developed an enterprise app-store for my company on iOS which comprises of many company apps. Now this app-store is basically same as that of a play-store. Is it possible to push an update to my app-store silently, without users intervention. If yes then how?
Any suggestion will really be appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think that this is not possible. I think you have to use some sort of mobile device management (MDM) solutions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) that enable you to push the updates / updated apps to the mobile phones.
Here are a view examples:
- https://www.relution.io/en/
- https://www.mobileiron.com/en

Comment: Is their any official documentation by Apple which states that ,silent updates are not possible in case of enterprise apps?